# Heroku can't read my .slug-post-clean file

Tags: heroku, size, slug, heroku-cli

I used a `.slug-post-clean` file to reduce my Heroku slug size error: Compiled slug size: 2.5G is too large (max is 500M) but it seems like it's not able to read the file.

```
-----> POST BUILD CLEAN app detected
Location node-modules/.cache not found - ignoring
Location .DS_Store/ not found - ignoring
Location .vscode/ not found - ignoring
Location logs not found - ignoring
Location temp-file.tmp not found - ignoring
Location tsconfig.json not found - ignoring
Location README not found - ignoring
Location .git not found - ignoring
Location .vscode not found - ignoring
Location .idea/ not found - ignoring
Location node_modules not found - ignoring
Location node_modules/ not found - ignoring
Location src not found - ignoring
Removing directory public from slug
Location test not found - ignoring
Location spec not found - ignoring
Location tmp/cache/webpacker not found - ignoring
```

My VSCode, React + Django:

[image]

here is my `.slug-post-clean`:

```
node-modules/.cache
.DS_Store/
.vscode/
logs
temp-file.tmp
tsconfig.json
README
.git
.vscode
.idea/
node_modules
node_modules/
src
public
test
spec
tmp/cache/webpacker
```

Comment: `.slug-post-clean` isn't a native Heroku thing. You must be running [a custom buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/search/buildpacks?q=post+build+clean) or something. Please [edit] further details into your question so we can understand and answer it.

Comment: (Aside: It looks like Heroku is reading that file just fine. The error message you show at the beginning of your question lists the same patterns that you show in the file. The problem is that whatever non-standard tool reads that file isn't doing what you expect it to do.)